# Issue with node start from cassandra CCM (Timed out waiting for dirty_pid file)

Tags: cassandra

I am very new to Cassandra. I am unable to start nodes locally using CCM. I am getting this error. Anyone is having any idea about this error.

```
D:\ccm>python ccm status
node1: DOWN (Not initialized)
node3: DOWN (Not initialized)
node2: DOWN (Not initialized)
D:\ccm>python ccm start
ERROR: Problem starting node1 (Timed out waiting for dirty_pid file.)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ccm", line 72, in <module>
    cmd.run()
  File "D:\ccm\ccmlib\cmds\cluster_cmds.py", line 458, in run
    profile_options=profile_options) is None:
  File "D:\ccm\ccmlib\cluster.py", line 260, in start
    p = node.start(update_pid=False, jvm_args=jvm_args, profile_options=profile_
options)
  File "D:\ccm\ccmlib\node.py", line 459, in start
    self.__clean_win_pid()
  File "D:\ccm\ccmlib\node.py", line 1183, in __clean_win_pid
    raise Exception('Error while parsing <node>/dirty_pid.tmp in path: ' + self.
get_path())
Exception: Error while parsing <node>/dirty_pid.tmp in path: C:\Users\Ram\.ccm\cluster2\node1

D:\ccm>
```

Please help on this.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this example of using ccm to trace consistency changes: http://www.datastax.com/documentation/cql/3.1/cql/cql_using/useTracingSetup.html

If you are not using Cassandra source code, the procedure is a little different. See the ccm README or let me know and I'll send you the details.

Don't forget to set up the alias on the local ip, for example:

```
$ sudo ifconfig lo0 alias 127.0.0.2 up
$ sudo ifconfig lo0 alias 127.0.0.3 up
$ sudo ifconfig lo0 alias 127.0.0.4 up
$ sudo ifconfig lo0 alias 127.0.0.5 up
```